# MSChart DateTime only shown as OLE-Automation

Tags: c#, datetime, ole, mschart

I have 3 ChartAreas in 1 Chart each is initalized the same way (only other names). Each ChartArea has its own Series (still initialized the same way) which are filled as follows:

```
DateTime Datum = Pair.Key;
                    if (Datum1_gewählt.Contains(Datum))
                    {
                        foreach (Tuple<DateTime, int> t in Pair.Value)
                        {
                            //Füge Messwert mit Zeit der aufzeichnung hinzu
                            mySeriesHRM1.Points.AddXY(t.Item1, t.Item2);
                        }
                    }
                    if (Datum2_gewählt.Contains(Datum))
                    {
                        foreach (Tuple<DateTime, int> t in Pair.Value)
                        {
                            //Füge Messwert mit Zeit der aufzeichnung hinzu
                            DataPoint pt = new DataPoint(t.Item1, t.Item2);
                            mySeriesHRM2.Points.Add(pt);
                        }
                    }
                    if (Datum3_gewählt.Contains(Datum))
                    {
                        foreach (Tuple<DateTime, int> t in Pair.Value)
                        {
                            //Füge Messwert mit Zeit der aufzeichnung hinzu
                            mySeriesHRM3.Points.AddXY(t.Item1, t.Item2);
                        }
                    }
```

As you see each Series is filled with die actual Date(x axis) and an double value (y axis).
**My Problem is that in Chartarea 1 all Dates are displayd correctly, but in the other areas as OLE automation.** Anyone know why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  Chart.Series.XValueType property to "DateTime", "Date" or "Time",

More Info here:
http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=761

Comment: Thanks a lot, so simple, but i didnt find it... :)